# Python: typed method arguments

Tags: python, callback, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

In Python3 it's possible to add the type to the arguments of a function:

```
def foo(bar: str = "default") -> str:
    """
    @param bar: a textual value
    """
    return "test"
```

Now I got two questions. First, how can you do that for a **callback function**? Meaning, how to define the signature of that callback in the function header?

```
def foo(callback) -> str:
    """
    @param callback: function(value: str) -> str
    """
    # calculate some intermediate stuff
    my_var = ...    
    return callback(my_var)
```

Second, how to do that **for tuples**. This would include the defining that the value is of type tuple and should have two values (no triple etc.).

```
def foo(value) -> str:
    """
    @param value: tuple of strings
    """

    v1, v2 = value
    return v1 + v2
```

Thanks for your comments and answers.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: A callback is a callable

Comment: but a callback must satisfy a signature in which is needs to be invoked. See example above.

Comment: In your example callback annotation would be `typing.Callable[[str], str]`

Comment: One more problem: if you define a static method inside a class whereas that method has arguments of the same type/class, then that type is unknown ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the signature of your callback function, you can use [Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable), like this:

```
from typing import Callable


def foo(callback: Callable[[str], str]) -> str:
    # calculate some intermediate stuff
    my_var = '...'
    return callback(my_var)
```

For a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple) of two strings, you can use:

```
from typing import Tuple


def foo(value: Tuple[str, str]) -> str:
    v1, v2 = value
    return v1 + v2
```